# How to list available options of git sub command

Tags: git, manpage

I know that there is `git stash show -p` to show the diff of the stash. But When I do `git stash show -h` it does not show the available options. Where can I find the available options for `git stash show` command? Note that I want the options for `show` sub command not `stash`

```
git stash show -h
usage: git stash list [<options>]
   or: git stash show [<options>] [<stash>]
                       ^^^^^^^^^ How can I find available options for git stash show?
   or: git stash drop [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git stash ( pop | apply ) [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git stash branch <branchname> [<stash>]
   or: git stash clear
   or: git stash [push [-p|--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
                 [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-m|--message <message>]
                 [--pathspec-from-file=<file> [--pathspec-file-nul]]
                 [--] [<pathspec>...]]
   or: git stash save [-p|--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
                 [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [<message>]
```

Comment: Can't u simply run `git help stash`, scroll down a bit and read the `OPTIONS` section where they are  all listed?

Comment: Ah. didn't even know there is a help command. Yes `git help stash` shows `<diff-options>` are available. I can do another help to list available options `git help diff`

Comment: In Git, you can also use `--help` to get the full documentation. So `git stash --help` is the same as `git help stash`.